# android studio 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to learn login in Kotlin in Android Studio, in which I need to register by using keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore
in terminal window.

But I am getting this error 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Operating system is Win 10 and android studio is 3.6

Comment: fix your `$PATH`

Comment: Can you please tell me in little detail because what you said I already try to do, but not getting result

Comment: when I try to search keytook.exe in cmd then its working but its not working directly in Android Studio.

Comment: @Marcin Orlovski: Variable in windows is defined this way `%path%` not `$path`

Comment: keytool is working after a reboot but now I am getting this error Illegal option:  -V\-alias,  Keystore file does not exist

Comment: Done everything worked now

Answer (score -1):

Use command `where keytool.exe` and include founded path (without `filename.ext`) at the end of `%path%` system variable, than reboot computer.

Comment: PLease mark answer as a solution of problem. Thanks

Comment: Solution is pretty simple, just add JDK in environment variables-> path, then reboot your android studio and it will work.